# Identical anchor ids on two pages: How to link from one page to the anchor on the other page

Tags: html, wordpress, hyperlink, href

I have two websites page1 and page2. On every page there is a download form which I can access through the anchor id #DownloadForm.

On page1 I'd like to create a link to the download form on page2. I thought this would work:

```
<a href="/page2#DownloadForm"></a>
```

But when clicking on this link (in Chrome) it takes me to the download form on page1. As if the anchor expression was evaluated first and then the rest of the href is ignored.

Btw: I'm using Wordpress but I guess that's not relevant here.

If anyone has a hint for me, I'd highly appreciate!

Comment: If you change the `id` of the element on page2 (and update the link) temporarily does the link work? I'm very surprised that it doesn't work as-is (and I'm assuming you've checked for typos?)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the full page uri? I tried this and it worked for me in chrome and firefox.

```
<a href="/page2.html#DownloadForm"></a>
```

Comment: Some websites are set up to not use any extension. It is entirely possible that the `.html` extension for OP's website would result in a 404.

Comment: Sorry, you are using Wordpress, so the full path ends with php. I would place the form in an iframe that would have an html ext and reference it this way. But may not be appropriate for all cases of course

Comment: ajp15243 True, but in WP they can get a full path to a page, but anchors wont work with php ext.